# LSI MegaRAID SAS 3108: Restoring the online state from Foreign Bad (Frn-Bad) state

Tags: raid5, data-recovery, lsi, megaraid, virtual-drive

We have a Virtual Disk in RAID 5 using only 5 disks, one disk probably is broken because it was in an alert before. Another disk was accidentally pulled out and then it was marked as Frn-Bad when it was put back in the same slot. So, the 2 disks are marked as Frn-Bad and the 3 others are Online. The RAID 5 doesn't work with only 3 discs.

I think we can restore the virtual disk if we put this potentially good disk that is today in the "Frn-Bad" state as "Online". What do you think? Is it possible to use the LSI MegaRaid controller interface for this?

Just like following the instructions here: Restoring a Hard Drive in Frn-Bad State

Thanks for any help with this. I can't go wrong and lose the virtual disk.

[LSI MegaRAID BIOS Configuration Utility - PD Mgmt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJHXg.jpg)
[LSI MegaRAID BIOS Configuration Utility - Virtual Drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ9Dz.jpg)

- There is another disk (SSD-SATA) also in there but I don't know if it is part of the array maybe as a cache

Comment: Anything you do can potentially damage your RAID array at this point. If the data is as valuable as you suggest, you should now, before you do anything else, get images of all five disks as best you can, and work with those images. Yes, it will cost money to get the replacement disks and software, but what is the data worth?

Comment: It's really difficult to estimate the worth of these data. But anyway, what do you suggest to generate the images and work with them? Something that does not compromise the current state.

Comment: Site guidelines prevent my suggesting brands. I've seen standalone devices which you drop a pair of disks into, and they make a bitwise copy; there is a lot of software that claims to make a copy of an entire disk, look for "disk imaging software"; and there is the Linux `dd` command that could be used to copy an entire disk to another or to a file. I'll mention that on the Windows side I've worked with Zero Assumption Recovery and their imaging software, but don't know if that will help here.

Comment: I had to stop this to solve other problems and decided to take a look here in this thread. I haven't done anything yet. About using a copy of the disk, the big issue there is that the RAID stores the IDs of the disks so, even if copying using dd to other disks would have problems in rebuild the RAID because the disks will be different (distinct IDs from the original).